The largest prime divisor of integer $x$ satisfying $\left[\frac x{1!}\right]+\left[\frac x{2!}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac x{10!}\right]=1001$

$x$ is an integer satisfying:
$$\left[\frac x{1!}\right]+\left[\frac x{2!}\right]+\left[\frac x{3!}\right] + \cdots +\left[\frac x{10!}\right]=1001$$
Find largest prime divisor of $x$, where $[~]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

I have no idea of solving questions of these format. Any solutions are highly requested.
I know basic Gif operations, identities like $[x] =[x/2]+[(x+1)/2]$ which can be generalised for any natural number $n$.

I'd start with finding some bounds on $x$... How big or how small can $x$ be if you take just the first or last term?  If you assume all terms equal the first or last?  Then you can start adjusting for two or three terms at a time, until you've limited $x$ down to a manageable set of numbers and just check a few...

binary search works pretty quickly here.

Solving $\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x}{3!}+\cdots + \frac{x}{11!}+\cdots=1001$ for real $x$ is easy. Then try nearby integers in your expression

OEIS A060832 is related

I don't think that this is an equation that you solve. It is an equation where you guess and check.

@lulu sorry but I am not aware of binary search

Binary search:  One easy way to do it, Find $n$ such that $2^n<x<2^{n+1}$.  Then test the midpoint of that interval to see which part $x$ is in, and so on.  Nothing special about powers of $2$, just happened to be what I thought to try.

Since $\left[\frac{x}{1!}\right] = [x] = x$, then $x\leq 1001$. Since $6!=720$, then $\frac{x}{6!} < 1$ and $\left[\frac{x}{6!}\right] = 0$. This cuts down the possibilities and the computation you have to do.

A lot of people gave great hints in the comment, but I'll answer just so this post has one
First, the left side is strickly increasing over the integer. So, if we find a value that work, it is the only one. Also, if a value of $x$ give something smaller than $1001$, then the answer is bigger. The reciprocal is also true. We could narrow our possibilities by doing a binary search.
Since $x$ is an integer,
$$\left[\frac{x}{1!}\right] = [x]$$
Then $x\leq1001$
Follow up $6!=720$, then
$$\frac{x}{6!} <1 \Longrightarrow \left[\frac{x}{6!}\right] = 0$$
We are left with
$$\left[\frac{x}{1!}\right]+\left[\frac{x}{2!}\right]+\left[\frac{x}{3!}\right]+\left[\frac{x}{4!}\right]+\left[\frac{x}{5!}\right]=1001$$
Adding the term up to further reduce the possibilities. If we just have
$$\left[\frac{x}{1!}\right]+\left[\frac{x}{2!}\right]=1001$$
Then $x$ should be around two third of $1001$. Let's try $x=667$
$$\left[\frac{667}{1!}\right]+\left[\frac{667}{2!}\right]=667+333=1000$$
$x<668$. Here it doesn't help but if the numbers were bigger, it could have remove more terms from the sum.
Finally, if we remove the $[\cdot]$ function, then $x$ is
$$\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x}{3!}+\frac{x}{4!}+\frac{x}{5!} = \frac{120x+60x+20x+5x+1x}{120}$$
$$\frac{206x}{120}=1001 \Longrightarrow x = 583.106\ldots$$
Let's try $x=584$
$$\left[\frac{584}{1!}\right]+\left[\frac{584}{2!}\right]+\left[\frac{584}{3!}\right]+\left[\frac{584}{4!}\right]+\left[\frac{584}{5!}\right]=584+292+97+24+4=1001$$

Edit to include Henry comment
If we continue the sum, the equation could become
$$\left[\frac{x}{1!}\right]+\left[\frac{x}{2!}\right]+\left[\frac{x}{3!}\right]+\dots+\left[\frac{x}{11!}+\dots\right]=1001$$
The left hand part is becomes $x(e-1)$ and
$$x=\frac{1001}{e-1}\approx 582.56$$
From there, we test $583$ and, since it is too low, $584$.

Edit 2 to answer the question
Thank's to Mark who point out that I forgot to answer to the question which is "Find the largest divisor of $x$". Since $584 = 2^3\times73$, the answer is $73$.

You can also argue that the left side is strictly increasing over the integers so there is at most one solution.

Thank's, I'll add it. I use it without mentionning it.

Starting with the real solution to the unrounded untruncated $\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x}{3!}+\cdots + \frac{x}{11!}+\cdots=1001$ which is $\dfrac{1001}{e-1} \approx 582.56$ (but too small for the actual question and not an integer) would involve testing $583$ unsuccessfully and then $584$ successfully.

Thank's @Henry I've added it to my answer.

And since the question is: "Find largest prime divisor of x", and x=584. We get $584 = 2^3 \times 73$. So the answer is 73.

$$\underset{{n}=\mathrm{1}} {\overset{\mathrm{10}} {\sum}}\left[\frac{{x}}{{n}!}\right]=\mathrm{1001} \\ $$
$${x}\left({e}−\mathrm{1}\right)\in\left[\mathrm{1001};\mathrm{1012}\right) \\ $$
$$\left[{x}\right]\in\left[\mathrm{583};\mathrm{588}\right] \\ $$
$$\left[\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{1}!}\right]+\left[\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{2}!}\right]+\left[\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{3}!}\right] \\ $$
$$=\mathrm{1001}−\mathrm{24}−\mathrm{4} \\ $$
$$\left[{x}\right]+\left[\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{2}}\right]+\left[\frac{{x}}{\mathrm{6}}\right]=\mathrm{973} \\ $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{10}{x}}{\mathrm{6}}\in\left[\mathrm{973};\mathrm{976}\right) \\ $$
$$\left[{x}\right]=\left[\mathrm{584};\mathrm{585}\right] \\ $$
$$\left[{x}\right]=\mathrm{973}−\mathrm{292}−\mathrm{97}=\mathrm{584} \\ $$
$$=\mathrm{73}\centerdot\mathrm{8} \\ $$
$$?=\mathrm{73} \\ $$
